# Tool to search jsfiddle for specific term/technique?

Tags: search, jsfiddle

If I wanted to search jsfiddle for examples of a specific concept or technique, I don't see a way to do that.

Can someone point to a tool that would allow a search of fiddles, or if nothing else, a pointer page that has attempted to group examples of a wide array of various techniques demonstrated and/or terms used in fiddles?

Comment: You can use Google to limit your search to a single website.

Comment: It's not possible at the moment (from within of jsFiddle or API)

Comment: @Jay Your suggestion worked for what I was looking for.  If you throw this in as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*jsfiddle.net* doesn't have a feature to search for the posted codes, but Google or other capable web seach engines can be used to searh for specific keyword(s) from a single website.

For Google example, use below search query:

```
keyword site:jsfiddle.net
```

Or for two keywords and both must exist:

```
"keyword1" "keyword2" site:jsfiddle.net
```